# JQuery: If a table header <th> has a class, add class to table cell <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Let's say I have the following html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="alignRight">Header1</th>
            <th>Header2</th>
            <th class="alignLeft">Header3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row1</td> //Add class="alignRight"
            <td>Row1</td>
            <td>Row1</td> //Add class="alignLeft"
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row2</td> //Add class="alignRight"
            <td>Row2</td>
            <td>Row2</td> //Add class="alignLeft"
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row3</td> //Add class="alignRight"
            <td>Row3</td>
            <td>Row3</td> //Add class="alignLeft"
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If a TR in the THEAD contains the class "alignRight" or "alignLeft" I would like to apply the same class to the corresponding TD in the TBODY.

I'm using JQuery and have tried the following, but none of them seem to work properly:

```
$('tr').has('th.alignRight').addClass('th.alignRight');
$('tr').has('th.alignLeft').addClass('th.alignLeft');

$('thead.tr').has('th.alignRight').addClass('tbody.th.alignRight');
$('thead.tr').has('th.alignLeft').addClass('tbody.th.alignLeft');

if ($('thead.tr').has('th.alignRight')){
    $('tbody.tr').addClass('th.alignRight');
}

if ($('thead.tr').has('th.alignRight')){
    $('tbody.tr.td').addClass('alignRight');
}
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I would like to add that I already iterate through the table using a .each() loop.  I only need to add the condition that if the current table header has that class, add that same class to the table cell.  Adding in an extra iteration during the current iteration sounds like it would lead to performance issues.  Is that true?

**LOOP:**

```
function(res) {
    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(res, function () {
        var tbl_row = "";
        $.each(this, function (k, v) {

          //Irrelevant code

            tbl_row += "<td>" + v + "</td>";
        })
        tbl_body += "<tr>" + tbl_row + "</tr>";
    })
    $("#print").html(tbl_body);
    },
    //Other irrelevant code
```

Comment: Please post your loop. But in all cases you will have to loop on your `td`s.

Comment: @OlivierH res = result.  It's not used in this case.

Comment: I don't understand your loop, and so how to modify it to put the classes. Just do another loop later as we wrote it : you won't have performance issues, except if your table has thousands of rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you don't see how jquery selectors work.
`$('thead.tr')` means : find me all `thead` which has the `tr` class. Visibly not what you want to do.

Here a code that should work :

```
$('tbody tr td').each(function(index){
    //index contains the current td index in the parent tr (1,2,3),(1,2,3)...
    //if the corresponding th has a class
    if($('thead tr th').eq(index).attr('class') != ''){
        //put this class on the current td
        $(this).addClass($('thead tr th').eq(index).attr('class'));
    }
});
```

Checking if the td has a class is not necessary, since addClass does nothing if you give it an empty parameter.

Comment: Post your loop (see my comment)

Comment: I ultimately ended up getting it to work with your code.  So you get the check.  Arun's response probably would have gotten the check, but he uses `:nth-child` which has issues with IE8.

Comment: As I said, it's not a big deal to parse two times tif you don't have a very huge table. And you can reduce this code to a single line.

Comment: You're right, but there is a possibility that the table could get huge, so I wanted to code for that.  In the end, I only used the code from your if condition.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$('table thead th[class]').each(function () {
    $('table tbody td:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').addClass(this.className)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s5D7e/)

Comment: @ArunPJohny seems to be one of those days, +1

Comment: I already have a .each function that iterates through the table rows.  What I need is a function that just checks the current table head for a class, and if it does, add that class to the table cell.  Is nesting .each() functions a problem?

Comment: @I didn't include it.  I didn't think it was necessary since all I am concerned about is adding the class if a certain condition is met.

Comment: I added the loop.  See above.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
// find all tr's that have a th with class `alignRight` and add class `th.alignRight` to them
$('tr').has('th.alignRight').addClass('th.alignRight');
// find all tr's that have a th with class `alignLeft` and add class `th.alignLeft` to them
$('tr').has('th.alignLeft').addClass('th.alignLeft');
```

etc, etc.

Your code does **nothing** with the `<td>`'s

---

What *could* be done:

```
var thead = $('thead');
var tbody = $('tbody');

var rightIndex = $('th.alignRight', thead).index();
var leftIndex = $('th.alignLeft', thead).index();

$('tr', tbody).each(function(){
   $('td', this).eq(rightIndex).addClass('alignRight');
   $('td', this).eq(leftIndex).addClass('alignLeft');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

None of your addClass strings are valid. Whan adding a class you only provide the className.... no `dot` in it

```
/* would add class to the TR*/
$('tr').has('th.alignLeft').addClass('alignLeft');
```

Now to add to the TD can simply use selector

```
$('tr th.alignLeft td').addClass('alignLeft');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution: [(fiddle here)](http://jsfiddle.net/8BZU4/)

```
var headrow = $('thead tr').children();
$('tbody tr').each(function(){
  var row = $(this).children();
  for(var i=0; i<headrow.length; ++i){
      if($(headrow[i]).hasClass("alignRight")){
          $(row[i]).addClass("alignRight");
      }
      if($(headrow[i]).hasClass("alignLeft")){
          $(row[i]).addClass("alignLeft");
      }
  }
});
```