# jquery - Add the th class to the child td's

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to add the class name available in the `th` tag to all dropdowns inside the corresponding th.

**For example:**

The second th has the class name 6. So need to add 6 as class name to all the dropdowns available in the second td's in the rows. I've tried the answer mentioned in this post: [JQuery: If a table header <th> has a class, add class to table cell <td>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958908/jquery-if-a-table-header-th-has-a-class-add-class-to-table-cell-td/19959054). But it's working fine in my case.

Thanks in advance.

```js
$('tbody tr td .get_hnos').each(function(index){
    debugger;
    //index contains the current td index in the parent tr (1,2,3),(1,2,3)...
    //if the corresponding th has a class
    if($('thead tr th').eq(index).attr('class') != ''){
        //put this class on the current td
        $(this).addClass($('thead tr th').eq(index).attr('class'));
    }
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                                    
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Sr.</th> 
                                                                                        <th class="6">Title 1</th> 
                                                                                         <th class="7">Title 2</th> 
                                                                            
                                        </tr> 
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody><tr> </tr><tr><input type="hidden" name="sr_no" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="batch" value=""><input type="hidden" name="valve_no[]" value="1"><td>1</td><td><select name="1[]" class="get_hnos" id="1"><option value="BH123" selected="">BH123</option>

</select> 
</td>
<td><select name="1[]" class="get_hnos 6" id="1">
<option value="H89" selected="">H89</option>
</select> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr> </tr><tr><input type="hidden" name="sr_no" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="batch" value=""><input type="hidden" name="valve_no[]" value="2"><td>2</td><td><select name="2[]" class="get_hnos 7" id="2"><option value="BH123" selected="">BH123</option>

</select> 
</td>
<td><select name="2[]" class="get_hnos" id="2">
<option value="H89" selected="">H89</option>
</select> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr> </tr><tr><input type="hidden" name="sr_no" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="batch" value=""><input type="hidden" name="valve_no[]" value="3"><td>3</td><td><select name="3[]" class="get_hnos" id="3"><option value="BH123" selected="">BH123</option>

</select> 
</td>
<td><select name="3[]" class="get_hnos" id="3">
<option value="H89" selected="">H89</option>
</select> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr> </tr><tr><input type="hidden" name="sr_no" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="batch" value=""><input type="hidden" name="valve_no[]" value="4"><td>4</td><td><select name="4[]" class="get_hnos" id="4"><option value="BH123" selected="">BH123</option>

</select> 
</td>
<td><select name="4[]" class="get_hnos" id="4">
<option value="" selected=""></option>
</select> 
</td>
</tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through tr inside that loop through `tds` and then using index see if class of  `th` is undefined then only add class to your select-box.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("tbody tr").each(function() {
  //loop thrh td
  $(this).find('td').each(function(index) {
    if ($('thead tr th:eq(' + index + ')').attr('class') != undefined) {
      //assign class to select
      $(this).find('select').addClass($('thead tr th:eq(' + index + ')').attr('class'));

    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr.</th>
      <th class="6">Title 1</th>
      <th class="7">Title 2</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> </tr>
    <tr><input type="hidden" name="sr_no" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="batch" value=""><input type="hidden" name="valve_no[]" value="1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <select name="1[]" class="get_hnos" id="1">
          <option value="BH123" selected="">BH123</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="1[]" class="get_hnos" id="1">
          <option value="H89" selected="">H89</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> </tr>
    <tr><input type="hidden" name="sr_no" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="batch" value=""><input type="hidden" name="valve_no[]" value="2">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <select name="2[]" class="get_hnos" id="2">
          <option value="BH123" selected="">BH123</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="2[]" class="get_hnos" id="2">
          <option value="H89" selected="">H89</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> </tr>
    <tr><input type="hidden" name="sr_no" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="batch" value=""><input type="hidden" name="valve_no[]" value="3">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>
        <select name="3[]" class="get_hnos" id="3">
          <option value="BH123" selected="">BH123</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="3[]" class="get_hnos" id="3">
          <option value="H89" selected="">H89</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> </tr>
    <tr><input type="hidden" name="sr_no" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="batch" value=""><input type="hidden" name="valve_no[]" value="4">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>
        <select name="4[]" class="get_hnos" id="4">
          <option value="BH123" selected="">BH123</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="4[]" class="get_hnos" id="4">
          <option value="" selected=""></option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you look into this plz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66183431/jquery-append-to-the-multiple-dropdowns-for-matching-array-keys-as-class-name ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified somewhat, and it probably makes more intuitive sense to begin from the point of (i.e. loop over) the `th` tags.

```
let table = $('table');
table.find('th').each((i, th) => {
    table.find('td:nth-child('+(i+1)+')')[0].className = th.className;
});
```

Note: This adds the *same* class(es) that the `th` has to the corresponding `td`s. If the `th` has multiple classes, and only one/some of them should be transferred to the `td`s, you would have to further code some sort of class filtering, to establish which class(es) were transferred.

Also note that this transfers classes to `td`s, but your code seems to suggest you want the classes instead to be transferred to a *child* of the `td`s (`.get_hnos`).

Comment: Classes are not getting added dropdowns with the above code.

Comment: *Read* my last paragraph. Your question asks for the classes to be transferred to the `tds`, not the dropdowns. If you want to transfer classes to the dropdowns, be clear about that.

Comment: Yes, I want to add it to the dropdowns.

Comment: Then please edit your question, because you don't ask for that. If you want to add to the dropdowns, just extend the selector in the line `table.find('td:nth-child('+(i+1)+')')` to go deeper to the dropdown.